# How to make this wizard responsive?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, github-pages

I'm trying to use this work

[Bootstrap Application Wizard Hosted in Github](https://github.com/Mr-Kumar-Abhishek/bootstrap-application-wizard/)

to create a wizard, but i need a full-width and responsive wizard.

In docs, `contentHeight` and `contentWidth` are the properties to resize the wizard, but they are in pixels, not in percentage.

I tried adding classes to the modal with some css, but i failed because the dimensions are calculated with js. Any help will be appreciated.

[Github Demo](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/Mr-Kumar-Abhishek/bootstrap-application-wizard/blob/master/demo/demo.html)

[Github Js](https://rawgit.com/Mr-Kumar-Abhishek/bootstrap-application-wizard/master/src/bootstrap-wizard.js)

[My Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jechaviz/7m6ntv52/)

Snippet to modify:

```
autoDimensions: function() {
        // DO NOT REMOVE DISPLAY ; Temporary display is required for calculation
        this.modal.css('display', 'block');

        this.dimensions.header = this.header.outerHeight(true);

        // Navigation Pane is dyanmic build on card content
        // Navigation Pane === BASE Inner Content Height
        this.dimensions.navigation = this.wizardSteps.outerHeight(true);
        if ( this.dimensions.navigation < this.dimensions.contentHeight ) {
            this.dimensions.navigation = this.dimensions.contentHeight;
            this.navContainer.height( (this.dimensions.contentHeight-30) - this.progressContainer.outerHeight(true));
        }

        // Dimension Alias ( Body Height === (Navigation Height) )
        this.dimensions.body = this.dimensions.navigation;

        // Apply OuterHeight of navigation to it's parent wizardSteps
        this.wizardSteps.height(this.dimensions.body);

        // Modal Height === (Header + Content)
        this.dimensions.modal = (this.dimensions.header + this.dimensions.navigation);
        this.content.height(this.dimensions.modal + 'px');
        this.dialog.width(this.dimensions.contentWidth);

        this.body.height(this.dimensions.body + 'px');
        this.wizardCards.height(this.dimensions.body + 'px');

        // Footer Height
        this.dimensions.footer = this.footer.outerHeight(true);

        // Card Container === (Body - Footer)
        this.dimensions.cardContainer = (this.dimensions.body - this.dimensions.footer);
        this.wizardCardContainer.height(this.dimensions.cardContainer);

        // Reposition
        this.dimensions.offset = ($(window).height() - this.dialog.height()) / 2;           
        this.dialog.css({
            'margin-top': this.dimensions.offset + 'px',
            'padding-top': 0
        });

        // DO NOT REMOVE NEXT LINE
        this.modal.css('display', '');
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

In */src/bootstrap-wizard.js* :

- Comment `// this.dialog.width(this.dimensions.contentWidth);` because we want our modal to be responsive and not to set a width.
- Remove `'margin-top': this.dimensions.offset + 'px',` This can be replaced by a media query.
- After `container: el.parents('.form-group')` add `placement: 'top'`. Without this, default popover behavior is to show on the right of the control they are attached on. On small screens, they appear out off screen.

It now reads like this (note the coma at the end of first line) :

```
var popover = el.popover({
    content: msg,
    trigger: "manual",
    html: allowHtml,
    container: el.parents('.form-group'),
    placement: 'top'
}).addClass("error-popover").popover("show").next(".popover");
```